Is it possible to make a dependent workflow show under the commit interface?
When I push up a commit I see a check or a X:

But when I click that check I see

Notice there is only one box there for the "flow" that flow is the image flow, it was triggered. There is another flow that depends on that, and has this
name: Build documentation
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [Build cpanel-redocly image]
    types: [completed]
    branches: main

However, the Build documentation doesn't show up under that push. It only shows up under the Action Tab?

Is there anyway to elevate this so it shows up on the main overview with other Workflows that run on:push? Dependent jobs seem to do that. But Dependent Workflows do not seem to do that, even if what they depend on is on:push?
